# Which non-free code gets installed by default in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, proprietary, open-source

**Which non-free components/programs ship with Ubuntu 12.04?** I’m not referring to non-free software available from the repositories, but only to software that gets installed by default. (I’m not sure if the [offer to install third-party software](https://askubuntu.com/q/22285/82665) is available in 12.04, but let’s assume that this option doesn’t get selected).

"Non-free" = everything not licensed under a [free license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#SoftwareLicenses) (as defined by the *GNU Project*).

I read that the Linux kernel includes non-free blobs. True? If so, which parts are non-free? Only some specific hardware drivers?

Anything else?

Comment: this might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/247757/how-do-you-find-the-licenses-for-everything-installed-on-your-system

Comment: Related: [Is the Ubuntu kernel 100% free software?](http://askubuntu.com/q/229598/82665)