# Where is the installed kernel source located?

Tags: kernel, source-code, source

I have installed kernel source with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source -y
```

Now, where is the source located?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The kernel source code installed by the [linux-source](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-source) [image: Install linux-source] package is installed in the form of a compressed archive in the `/usr/src` directory. For example, if you are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the kernel source archive will be at `/usr/src/linux-source-3.13.0.tar.bz2`. You can unpack the source code in your current directory wherever you like to view it with

```
tar jxf /usr/src/linux-source-3.13.0.tar.bz2
```

If instead you would like to know how to get and prepare the kernel source for building your own custom kernel, see the Ubuntu help document on [compiling your own kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile)  or these other questions and answers:

- [Where can I find the source code for the Ubuntu Kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2964/70254)
- [Is the Ubuntu kernel open source and available for download and building?](https://askubuntu.com/q/171707/70254)
- [How do I get the kernel source code?](https://askubuntu.com/q/159833/70254)

Answer (score 7):

In general, to find the files installed by a package, use `dpkg -L <packagename>`